# How do I get Full HTML View Function in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

i'm working on a mobile app project for a Wordpress blog.

I've got this blog's post content in HTML but most of their posts contain videos , instagram, youtube, twitter embed tags and none of the html packages supports those tags. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be getting the links of the images/videos and loading them as Flutter Widgets. As for the text, don't get it as HTML, use the [WordPress API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).